# Getting the biggest change in data in postgres table

Tags: postgresql, postgres-9.6

We're collecting lots of sensor data and logging them to a postgres DB.

Basic schema - cut down:

```
id | BIGINT PK
sensor-id| INT FK
location-id | INT FK
sensor-value | NUMERIC(0,2)
last-updated | TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE
```

I'm trying to get the biggest change in sensor data in the last day. By that I mean, out of all the sensors, sensor ids 4,5,6,7 changed the biggest compared to the previous day. Before that, I'm trying to get a SQL query to figure out the delta between last reading and latest reading.

I thought maybe the lead and lag functions would help, but my query doesn't quite give me the result I was after:

```
SELECT
    srd.last_updated,
    spi.title,
    lead(srd.value) OVER (ORDER BY srd.sensor_id DESC) as prev,
    lag(srd.value) OVER (ORDER BY srd.sensor_id DESC) as next
FROM
    sensor_rt_data srd
    join sensor_prod_info spi on srd.sensor_id = spi.id
where srd.last_updated >= NOW() - '1 day'::INTERVAL -- current_date - 1
ORDER BY
    srd.last_updated DESC
```

Simple dataset - making this up now because i can't login to the DB right now:

```
id|sensor,location,value,updated
1|1,1,24,'2017-04-28 19:30'
2|1,1,22,'2017-04-27 19:30'
3|2,1,35,'2017-04-28 19:30'
4|2,1,33,'2017-04-28 08:30'
5|2,1,31,'2017-04-27 19:30'
6|1,1,25,'2017-04-26 19:30'
```

Forgetting the join (that's for the user-friendly sensor tag name field staff need and the location), how do I workout which sensor has reported the biggest change in temperature over a time-series when they're grouped by sensor-id?

I'd be expecting:

```
updated,sensor,prev,next
'2017-04-28 19:30',1,24,22
'2017-04-28 19:30',2,33,31
```

(then from that, I can subtract and order to workout the top 10 sensors that have changed)

I noticed that Postgres 9.6 has some other functions too but want to try get Lead/Lag working first.

Comment: You'll get more answers if you paste valid SQL code (CREATE TABLE statements, INSERT statements, etc) into your question instead of descriptions of schemas (which won't work, because column names can't contain hyphens) and descriptions of datasets (whose column names don't match your table).

Answer (score 0):

Window function aren't a best fit for this kind of task. Try this:

```
select sensor, max(value)-min(value) as value_change
from sensordata
where updated>=?-'1 day'::interval
group by sensor
order by value_change desc
limit 1;
```

Not much use for indexes besides `updated` for this kind of query. It would be probably possible to use a specially crafted index if you would be looking the largest change for a calendar day instead of last 24 hours.